# Why isn't CSS working with apache2+mod_wsgi+python3+bottle?

Tags: html, css, jinja2, python-3.3, bottle

Background: I am trying to stand up an Amazon EC2 instance using the ubuntu server. I have installed Python3.3.2, mod_wsgi-3.5, apache2, and bottle and jinja2 for python3. I can get a regular webpage to load using all of these components, e.g. it recognizes the jinja2 templates, and correctly interpolates variables passed in the python code to the html files. Furthermore, if I change the html in `views/home.tmpl` to have `<body bgcolor="#b0c4de">` then I get the appropriate color.

Problem: I want to implement a good level of abstraction (and learn CSS in general), so I want my pages to have an external CSS to manage the HTML page attributes, etc. But I can't get things to work properly and I can't seem to figure out why.

Minimum (non)working example of the code:

My directory structure is:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-7:/var/www/helloworld$ ls -lrtR
.:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu   ubuntu    162 Feb  4 23:55 adapter.wsgi
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 1044 Feb  5 04:10 helloworld.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb  5 04:14 views

./views:
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu   ubuntu   4096 Feb  5 04:04 css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data  431 Feb  5 04:14 home.tmpl

./views/css:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 34 Feb  5 04:04 homestyle.css
```

`adapter.wsgi` is just a wrapper to launch bottle.default_app():

```
import sys, os, bottle
sys.path = ["/var/www/helloworld/"] + sys.path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import helloworld
application = bottle.default_app()
```

`helloworld.py` is pretty simple as well:

```
from bottle import default_app, debug, get, post, request, route, run
from bottle import jinja2_template as template
from bottle import jinja2_view as view

@route("/hello")
def hello(name=None):
    return template('home.tmpl', name=name)
```

`views/home.tmpl` has some jinja2-specific code, but is short. note the `<link ...>` line; I feel like this is where I'm having the trouble:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="views/css/homestyle.css">
    {% block head %}
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}Jinja2-Templated Webpage!</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% if name is string: %}
    Hello {{ name.title() }}
    {% else: %}
    Hello world...
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

and my `views/css/homestyle.css` is as simple as could be:

```
body {background-color: #b0c4de;}
```

I have tried moving the placement of homestyle.css to be in the `views` directory, or in the "top-level" directory (`/var/www/helloworld` here); I've also tried using different links in my `href=`, including an absolute path. All to no avail, I cannot get this CSS to color my webpage. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486224/bottle-static-files

Comment: ok, i'll try to sift through that and figure out what's going on; it's not immediately clear to me, but perhaps i need to spend (even) more time reading documentation. thanks!

Comment: You see, apache is dishing out the files - so any static content should probably still sit under the apache server.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, let Apache serve your css file; don't put it under `views`.  And remember that your stylesheet's href is relative to your web page's URI, not to the directory where Bottle runs.

So, if you hit the page at `http://myhost/hello`, then use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homestyle.css">
```

and put `homestyle.css` in `/var/www/helloworld/css/`.

Hope that helps!