# bottle - static files causing 303 errors

Tags: python, bottle

I am experimenting in Bottle/MongoDB extending the Blog Engine from one of the MongoDB University Courses.

I have added a header & footer template and added some simple JS, CSS and an image. These work fine on all the templates other than show_post view. The way that it seems to be set up is that the value passed in to the function includes the static files (css, js & png) as well as the URL variable for the blog post itself.

The values from the python console are:

- about to query on permalink =  TLxrBfyxTZjqOKqxgnUP
- 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [25/Feb/2014 15:08:09] "GET /post/TLxrBfyxTZjqOKqxgnUP HTTP/1.1" 200 37682
- about to query on permalink =  style.css
- 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [25/Feb/2014 15:08:09] "GET /post/style.css HTTP/1.1" 303 0
- about to query on permalink =  blog.js
- 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [25/Feb/2014 15:08:09] "GET /post/blog.js HTTP/1.1" 303 0
- about to query on permalink =  BL_logo.png
- 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [25/Feb/2014 15:08:09] "GET /post/BL_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 303 0
- 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [25/Feb/2014 15:08:09] "GET /post_not_found HTTP/1.1" 200 21
- 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [25/Feb/2014 15:08:09] "GET /post_not_found HTTP/1.1" 200 21
- 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [25/Feb/2014 15:08:09] "GET /post_not_found HTTP/1.1" 200 21

The code in question is:

```
# Displays a particular blog post
@bottle.get("/post/<permalink>")
def show_post(permalink="notfound"):

cookie = bottle.request.get_cookie("session")

username = sessions.get_username(cookie)
permalink = cgi.escape(permalink)

print "about to query on permalink = ", permalink
post = posts.get_post_by_permalink(permalink)

if post is None:
    bottle.redirect("/post_not_found")

# init comment form fields for additional comment
comment = {'name': "", 'body': "", 'email': ""}

return bottle.template("entry_template", dict(post=post, username=username, errors="", comment=comment))
```

How can I prevent the function being called at all if the 'permalink' is a file rather than a value from a query string?

Thanks,
Mark

**ANSWER**

With many thanks to Ron's answer below for pointing me in the right direction.

My error was down to the path to the static files being incorrect. I made the path dynamic by importing os and then changed the root value to **os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static/js')** and made the filepaths in my header.tpl absolute, e.g."/style.css".

```
@bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def stylesheets(filename):
    rootPath=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static/css')
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root=rootPath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've placed your assets under `/post`, they're conflicting with your `/post/<permalink>` route.

Typically, you would serve your assets (css, js, png) from their own directory; something like `/static/css/foo.css`.  That's what I'd recommend here.

Something along the lines of this:

```
@bottle.get("/post/<permalink>")
    def show_post(permalink="notfound"):
        # code to generate a post page goes here

@bottle.get("/static/<file_name:path>"):
    def static_file(file_name):
        return bottle.static_file(file_name, "/full/path/to/your/static/file/root/")
```

The relevant Bottle docs are [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files); or see one of the many [posts describing how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258941/593047) to serve static file from Bottle.

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for the answer. This is how I am serving the assets - @bottle.get('/<filename:re:.*\.js>')
def javascripts(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='static/js')