# BottlePy - Serve Static Files From Root Directory

Tags: python, routes, bottle

My filetree looks something like so

```
root/
├─ etc.../
├─ public/
│  ├─ static-file-1.example
│  ├─ etc...
```

I know I can make a route point to that directory `https://site/public/static-file-1.example` but I'd like to have to url like this `https://site/static-file-1.example`

I managed to achieve this like so

```
@app.get('/<filepath:path>')  
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='./public/')
```

But the problem here is that it overrides my other routes. Like if I type in `https://site/blog` it looks for that file instead of using the blog route.

Comment: Does `static-file-1` have an extension? Maybe you can [whitelist files by extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258941/6243352). If there's no extension, maybe add one and use routes (but if you have a lot of them and this won't scale, perhaps share more details about your use case).

Comment: maybe first create `@app.get('/blog')` and later `@app.get('/<filepath:path>')` and it may first find `blog` (as first matching route) and use correct function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `@app.get('/blog')` and later `@app.get('/<filepath:path>')`
and it will find `@app.get('/blog')` as first matching route for `http://site/blog`
and it will use correct function for `http://site/blog`

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, static_file

app = Bottle()

@app.get('/blog')
def hello():
    print('[DEBUG] blog')
    return "Hello World!"

@app.get('/<filepath:path>')  
def server_static(filepath):
    print('[DEBUG] static:', filepath)
    return static_file(filepath, root='./public/')
    
run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```